# Override a protected method, and try to call it from the super class

Tags: java, overriding, extends

My question comes from a project. So let me abstract away a bit unrelated details.

I have a JAVA public class A that has two protected static methods, foo() and bar(). The method foo() calls bar() in its body.

```
public class A{
  protected static foo(){
     ...
     bar()
     ...
  }
  protected static bar(){print("A.bar()");}

}
```

Now I also have a class B extending A. In B,  I override bar()

```
class B extends A{
  @Overrides
  static protected bar(){ print("A.bar() extended");

}
```

Finally, I call foo() from a class in B

```
class B extends A{
  ...
  public static main(){foo()} 
}
```

I cannot understand two points
1. The compiler (Eclipse) asks me to remove @Override annotation. Why?
2. Finally the main() outputs "A.bar()", which means the resolved bar() target is of class A, but I intended to override bar() and use the A's foo() to call the modified bar(). How can I do that?

What are your opinions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You cannot override static methods.
2. Since every method is static it refers to them statically. You first call `A.foo()` which in turn calls `A.bar()`. Since you don't have instances, overriding methods does not work.

You need to remove all the `static` from your code and use `new B().foo()` in your main.

Consider reading this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can't override static methods, only non-static instance methods. You're trying to use inheritance in a static environment, and that won't work. If you truly need inheritance (and often when you think you do, really you don't), then make the methods non-static.

Comment: To anyone up-voting me, I've already reached my vote max for the day. Please up-vote @Guillaume's similar answer (as I already have done). :)